# Why does the author switch from plural to singular in Psalms 35:8,10?

Tags: psalms, referent-identification, david

Psalms 35:8 NASB

> 8 
>   Let destruction come upon ***him*** unawares,
>   And let the net which he hid catch himself;
>   Into that very destruction let him fall.

Psalms 35:10 NASB

> 10 All my bones will say, “Lord, who is like You,
>   Who delivers the afflicted from ***him*** who is too strong for him,
>   And the afflicted and the needy from him who robs him?”

In the above Psalm the author writes in plural until verse 8,10 then  switches to the singular,then reverts back to the plural for the rest of the Psalm.

1) Why did the author switch from plural to singular?

2)Was the author referring to a particular person in the above texts?

Comment: I don’t understand. Where is the plural?

Answer (score 1):

In Tehillim (Psalms) 35:4-10, David writes direct curses against his multiple enemies and redundant praise for his single defender, ranging from :

1. In Tehillim 35:4, Multiple adjectives of #disrepute ("shamed", "embarrassed", "disgraced") are directly cursing enemies ("those who seek my life").

- [Psalm 35:4] "May those who seek my life be shamed and embarrassed; may those who plan my harm draw backward and be disgraced." (יֵבֹ֣שׁוּ וְיִכָּֽלְמוּ֘ מְבַקְשֵׁ֪י נַ֫פְשִׁ֥י יִסֹּ֣גוּ אָח֣וֹר וְיַחְפְּר֑וּ חֹ֜שְׁבֵ֗י רָֽעָתִֽי )

2. Yet in Tehillim 35:10, a Singular instance of #praise through a redundant question describing David's defender YHVH.

- [Psalm 35:10] : "All my bones shall say, YHVH, who is like You, Who saves the poor from him that is too strong for him, the poor and needy from his robber?" ( כָּ֥ל עַצְמֹתַ֨י | תֹּאמַרְנָה֘ יְהֹוָ֗ה מִ֥י כָ֫מ֥וֹךָ מַצִּ֣יל עָ֖נִי מֵֽחָזָ֣ק מִמֶּ֑נּוּ וְעָנִ֥י וְ֜אֶבְי֗וֹן מִגֹּֽזְלֽוֹ)

Answer (score -1):

Psalms are poetic and of a hymnal nature, so they would be led by one person in some portions and then the congregation would respond where it implies plurality.